# Casting result of malloc to char (not char*) - why doesn't compiler complain?

Tags: c, casting

```
tmpString = (char*)malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
tmpString = (char )malloc((strlen(name) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

What is the difference between these 2 lines?

My understanding is that the second line is wrong but from some reason the compiler says nothing.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.  If you clear that stuff out, your code looks a lot simpler and your won't run into these kinds of problems.

Comment: Enable warnings. All of them. The compiler will complain. There are many areas that (IMOHO), C isn't prohibitive enough .. but if it were, someone (somewhere) would get upset :D

Comment: @CarlNorum How is that conclusion related to the question?..

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking.  Adding extra (unnecessary) casts and then complaining about what the compiler does or doesn't do seems like complaining for the sake of complaining.  @pst has the right idea.

Comment: @CarlNorum 1. removing the `sizeof(char)` isn't related to the casting and the question. 2. Need to cast the result of `malloc` isn't related either. The essence of the question wouldn't change if instead of `malloc` there was an expression such as `tmpString = (char)p; //p is void*`

Comment: The second line is not what you want, but it's not wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line casts the (void) pointer that malloc returns into a pointer to char, thus preserving both its pointeredness. All it is telling the compiler is that "the memory at location X should be viewed as a character array".

The second cast turns the pointer returned by malloc into a single character. That's bad for multiple reasons:

- You lose the pointer as you've just turned the pointer into something completely different
- You're also losing the majority of the numerical value of the pointer because the size of the character is much less than the size of the pointer (in a lot of cases, the pointer is 32 or 64 bit in size but the character only 8 bit) and the "superfluous" bits get discarded.

I would think that a compiler with the warning level cranked up sufficiently high should warn about the second assignment.

Comment: Yeah, there should be a warning along the lines of "assignment makes pointer from integer without cast" in the second case.

Comment: No, because there **is** a cast. I think this example is a great argument that casts are harmful and should be considered code smells.

Comment: @R.., there is not a cast back from the `char` to the (presumably) pointer type of `tmpString`.  In fact, for exactly this case, `clang` says: `warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'char'`.  GCC tells me both about the cast: `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size` *and* about the assignment: `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast`.  And that's with no special flags whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

The second line is wrong (casting to a `char` will truncate the pointer to just one byte, making the data `tmpString` contains an invalid address), but all casts in C are unchecked so you'll never get an error over them.

Comment: The assignment to `tmpString` should cause a warning in the second case, if the compiler's using C99 or the warnings are turned up enough. Something like "assignment makes pointer from integer without cast".  That is, assuming `tmpString` is `char *` as one might expect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the second line has undefined behavior. Since the case is explicit the compiler simply assumes that you know what you're doing. Essentially, the second cast interprets the first byte of the pointer value as a character code. The last sentence is just illustrative - you can't even rely on that exactly that will happen.

Comment: @Carl Norum. I rolled back your edit because it depends on endianness

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan, no it doesn't depend on endianness - that was my point in the edit.  Your answer says "first byte", which is only true on a little-endian system.  That cast to `char` yields the least significant byte, regardless of endianness.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tmpString` has type `char *`, then the second line *should* be a constraint violation, at least under the [latest standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.5.16.1 Simple assignment
>
> **Constraints**
> 1 One of the following shall hold:<sup>112)</sup>
> — the left operand has atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed arithmetic type, and the right has
> arithmetic type;
> — the left operand has an atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed version of a structure or union
> type compatible with the type of the right;
> — **the left operand has atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed pointer type, and (considering
> the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) both operands are
> pointers to qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed versions of compatible types, and the type pointed
> to by the left has all the qualiﬁers of the type pointed to by the right;**
> — **the left operand has atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed pointer type, and (considering
> the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion) one operand is a pointer
> to an object type, and the other is a pointer to a qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed version of
> void, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualiﬁers of the type pointed to
> by the right;**
> — the left operand is an atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed pointer, and the right is a null
> pointer constant; or
> — the left operand has type atomic, qualiﬁed, or unqualiﬁed _Bool, and the right is a
> pointer.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: The standard says that any pointer type may be converted to any integer type, and vice versa. So a `char` would be implicitly converted to a compatible pointer type. (6.3.2.3)

Comment: @teppic:  The *cast* is legal, but the *assignment* is not.

Comment: The 'considering the type the left operand would have after lvalue conversion' part is what makes it ok -- lvalue conversion means that the right operand is converted to the type of the left, and the standard says they're compatible.